# Remove "repeats" in column values for R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How does one filter an R data.table by "pairs" of repeat values between columns?

I have the following R data.table with "repeats" between the rows, whereby the values mirror one another:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(A=c(1, 5, 9, 3, 7, 11), B=c(2, 6, 10, 4, 8, 12), 
     C=c(3, 7, 11, 1, 5, 9), D=c(4, 8, 12, 2, 6, 10),
     E=c(47, 21, 45, 27, 40, 33), F=c(27, 40, 33, 47, 21, 45))


print(dt)
#     A  B  C  D  E  F
# 1:  1  2  3  4 47 27
# 2:  5  6  7  8 21 40
# 3:  9 10 11 12 45 33
# 4:  3  4  1  2 27 47
# 5:  7  8  5  6 40 21
# 6: 11 12  9 10 33 45
```

By "mirror copies", I mean the following: if you look at rows 3, 4, 5, these are "mirror copies" of rows 0, 1, 2. Columns A and B in rows 0, 1, 2 are columns C and D in rows 3, 4, 5.

For example, in row 0, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] is [1, 2, 3, 4]. In row 3, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] is [3, 4, 1, 2].

This is true with columns E and F as well---E values in rows 0, 1, 2 are the F values in rows 3, 4, 5.

I would like to remove these "mirror copy" rows and only leave the "unique" pairs. The correct output above should be either:

```
##     A   B   C   D   E   F
## 1   1   2   3   4  47  27
## 2   5   6   7   8  21  40
## 3   9  10  11  12  45  33
```

or

```
##     A   B   C   D   E   F
## 1   3   4   1   2  27  47
## 2   7   8   5   6  40  21
##   11  12   9  10  33  45
```

but not both---only one copy of the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to loop over the rows and sort.  It may be faster in `collapse` i.e. use the faster version of `apply` `dapply` from `collapse`, specify the `MARGIN = 1` (i.e. loop over the rows) and apply the faster version of `sort` (`fsort`), then use `unique` applied on the new data `by` all the columns (or just `unique(dt1)`)

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse)
dt1 <- dapply(dt, MARGIN = 1, FUN = fsort)
unique(dt1, by = names(dt1))
   A  B  C  D  E  F
1: 1  2  3  4 27 47
2: 5  6  7  8 21 40
3: 9 10 11 12 33 45
```

---

Or use `duplicated`

```
dt[dt1[, !duplicated(.SD)]]
```

Comment: This is great! The package `collapse` looks amazing. Could you explain how the above solution works?

Comment: @EB2127 thanks, I updated with some desription

Comment: I would also re-add the answer with `dt[dt1[, !duplicated(.SD)]]`. Both work.

Comment: @EB2127 yes, but `unique` with `by` option is from `data.table` so i thought it would be more suitable for you as you are using `dat.atable`

Comment: Actually, in my example, `dt[dt1[, !duplicated(.SD)]]` conserves the order of the values in the columns, while `unique(dt1, by = names(dt1))` does not.

Comment: @EB2127 yes, that is true, I updated